# Convert an array to Observable Object to normal array of object in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I found lot of references to convert array of object to observable array of object, but not reverse from observable array of object to normal array of object?

This code return :

```
myObjects: myObjects[] = this.myService.getMyObjects();
```

***TS2322:Type 'Observable< myObjects[]>' is not assignable to type 'myObjects[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Observable< myObjects[]>'.***

How can I convert / cast ?

Thanks

Comment: This plunkr may be helpful: http://plnkr.co/edit/QvHEbg?p=info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to subscribe to it and store the value in a variable.

**WARNING**

*This is an asynchronous call, meaning that your data will be empty until you loaded everything.*

```
myObjects: myObjects[] = [];

ngOnInit(){
    this.myService.getMyObjects().subscribe( objects => {
        this.myObjects = objects;
    });
}
```

As it seems to be an http call, once the http call has finished, your data will be in the `myObjects` variable.